# Eclipse -- Avoid package related notification

Tags: java, eclipse

I insert wrong package in java file. Eclipse have notified Error format.
How to avoid these notifications?

Answer (score 2):

This is a compiler error. It tells you that something is wrong, so the only way to avoid it is to fix it.

Click the red icon on the left side and see the fix suggestions.

Comment: @Prabhakaran I did not understand your comment

Comment: @Prabhakaran - it doesn't make sense to me either.